# What would I have to add to my Rails app in order to get this relationship to work?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

My sql experience is a bit limited, but my Rails is on point.

I'm writing this raw sql :

```
select payments.payment_number as payment_payment_number, jobs.job_number from payments;
```

But getting this error :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'jobs.job_number' in 'field list'
```

I don't quite understand what my App is lacking in order to get this properly working. Can someone explain to me in Rails, what I would need to do in order to associate these two data points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have not `JOIN`ed in the `jobs` table. In order to make use of two tables, you must include both of them in your `FROM` clause and supply the appropriate `JOIN` conditions in an `ON` clause.

```
SELECT 
  payments.payment_number as payment_payment_number,
  jobs.job_number
FROM
 /* Substitute the correct column name for those in <> here */
 payments JOIN jobs ON payments.<job_number> = jobs.<job_number>
```

Substitute the correct column relationship names between `payments` and `jobs`.  I've used `job_number` as the column name in both tables.